# Start docker from command line

Tags: macos, docker

Is there a command for starting docker from the command line? While this works, it is quite lame:

```
$ open /Applications/Docker.app/
```

`$ docker` returns help text about docker cli commands.

Comment: If it's "lame" just alias it.

Comment: Try this `open --background -a Docker`.

Comment: Thanks Praveen. That works too. Don't need background though.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be setting up an `alias` and place it inside `~/.bashrc`

```
echo -e "\nopen-docker='open /Applications/Docker.app/'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding these `alias` to `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc`.

```
alias dock="open -a 'Docker'"
alias dock_start="open -a 'Docker'"
alias docker_start="open -a 'Docker'"
```